# Can't update sections in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have `tableView` and if I select one row I want to reload some sections. I can do this 2 times and after that I can't reload sections anymore. When I select a cell after two times it is not even calling `didSelectRow` method. The code below is in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`:

```
let sections : IndexSet = [SectionName.Criteria.rawValue, SectionName.RecentSearch.rawValue]
if !isAdvancedSearch {
    self.tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .top)
} else {
    self.tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .bottom)
}
```

Comment: Maybe not related, but `beginUpdates / endUpdates` has no effect at all in this case.

Comment: @vadian I have tried without them. It's the same

Comment: Remove the lines anyway.

Comment: well, this code should reload sections, so at first I would make sure that the underlying data are really getting changed, and second, confirm that in `cellForRowAt` you are properly reconfiguring the cells..

Comment: The one interesting thing: if I create `UITapGestureRecognizer` and add it to `contentView` of that cell, than it works fine

Comment: Are you deSelecting the row after performing the selection action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have created a new project and tried to make similar issue, but everything was working fine. Then I noticed that there is an `UIGestureRecognizer` on my `RecentSearch` cell. I have deleted it gesture and it works!